# How do I create new JSON data after every script run

Tags: python, json

I have JSON data stored in the variable data.

I want to make it write to a text file after every time it runs so I know which data json that is new instead of re-writting the same Json.

Currently, I am trying this:

```
Saving = firstname + ' ' + lastname+ ' - ' + email
with open('data.json', 'a') as f:
    json.dump(Saving, f)
    f.write("\n")
```

which just adds up to the json file and the beginning of the script where the first code starts, I clean it with

```
Infotext = "First name : Last name : Email"
    with open('data.json', 'w') as f:
        json.dump(Infotext, f)
        f.write("\n")
```

How can I make instead of re-write the same Json, instead create new file with *Infotext* information and then add up with *Saving*?

---

Output in Json:

```
"First name : Last name : Email"
Hello        World   - helloworld@test.com
Hello2           World   - helloworld2@test.com
Hello3           World   - helloworld3@test.com
Hello4           World   - helloworld4@test.com
```

Thats the outprint I wish to be. So basically it needs to start with

**"First name : Last name : Email"**

And then the Names, Lastname Email will add up below that until there is no names anymore.

[image]

So basically easy to say now - What I want is that instead of clearing and add to the same json file which is data.json, I want it to create to a newfile called data1.json - then if I rerun the program again tommorow etc - it gonna be data2.json and so on.

Comment: Use a datetime in the file name? I'm not sure I understand the question tbh.

Comment: What do you mean by datetime? :)

Comment: Exactly that; a datetime. `with open('{}_data.json'.format(datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y_%m_%d_%H_%M_%S')), 'w') as outfile:` but with some better organisation/PEP8 in the code.

Comment: Ohhh. Well that could be but will that create a new file though and how would I be able to open it in the script in that case?

Comment: It will create a new file, unless the code is run more than once per second (you could increase the granularity to microseconds etc. to get over that). As for finding the file, you'd have to read the whole directory file names, sort the file names, and take the last one. Perhaps it would be better to explain what you're trying to do because I can't see the application for this approach.

Comment: Oh I will update it how the json data I wish to look like maybe instead? Would that be any better?

Comment: The structure of your data _within_ the file seems irrelevant from my understanding of your question. What is the broader problem you're trying to address?

Comment: that file contents doesn't look like JSON.

Comment: @roganjosh My issue right now is that when I run the program at the start, I clean it with ```with open('data.json', 'w') as f:
        json.dump(Infotext, f)
        f.write("\n")``` Which will then give me the start in the json file *First name : Last name : email* - And then when the script is finished with randomized the names and emails the output gonna be more like I added in the edited code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a datetime in the file name, to create a unique file each time the code is run. In this case, granularity goes down to per-second so, if the code is run more than once per second, you will overwrite the existing contents of a file. In that case, step down to file names with microseconds in their name.

```
import datetime as dt
import json

time_script_run = dt.datetime.now().strftime('%Y_%m_%d_%H_%M_%S')
with open('{}_data.json'.format(time_script_run), 'w') as outfile:
    json.dump(Infotext, outfile)
```

This has multiple drawbacks:

1. You'll have an ever-growing number of files
2. Even if you load the file with the latest datetime in its name (and finding that file grows in run time), you can only see data as it was in the single time before the last run; the full history is very difficult to look up.

I think you're better using a light-weight database such as `sqlite3`:

```
import sqlite3
import random
import time

import datetime as dt

# Create DB 
with sqlite3.connect('some_database.db') as conn:
    c = conn.cursor()

    # Just for this example, we'll clear the whole table to make it repeatable
    try:
        c.execute("DROP TABLE user_emails")
    except sqlite3.OperationalError: # First time you run this code
        pass

    c.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS user_emails(
                     datetime TEXT,
                     first_name TEXT,
                     last_name TEXT,
                     email TEXT)
              """)

    # Now let's create some fake user behaviour
    for x in range(5):
        now = dt.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
        c.execute("INSERT INTO user_emails VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)", 
                  (now, 'John', 'Smith', random.randint(0, 1000)))
        time.sleep(1) # so we get new timestamps


# Later on, doing some work
with sqlite3.connect('some_database.db') as conn:
    c = conn.cursor()

    # Get whole user history
    c.execute("""SELECT * FROM user_emails 
                 WHERE first_name = ? AND last_name = ?
                 """, ('John', 'Smith'))
    print("All data")
    for row in c.fetchall():
        print(row)
    print('...............................................................')

    # Or, let's get the last email address
    print("Latest data")
    c.execute("""
              SELECT * FROM user_emails 
              WHERE first_name = ? AND last_name = ?
              ORDER BY datetime DESC
              LIMIT 1;
              """, ('John', 'Smith'))
    print(c.fetchall())
```

Note: the data retrieval runs really quickly in this code, it only takes ~5 secs to run because I use `time.sleep(1)` in generating the fake user data.

Comment: Yes this is exactly it! What I need now is that I just need it to add the generated names and email inside that code. So I need to somehow use the ```Saving = fname + ' ' + lname + ' - ' + email 
            with open('data.json', 'a') as f:
                json.dump(Saving, f)
                f.write("\n")``` in that file but how would I be able to save that file name so it adds inside the same json file that was created with your code?

Comment: @CDNthe2nd You would need to read in the initial data as in barmar's answer and modify it in some way. Your question and screenshots imply that this is _not_ valid JSON in the first place, so the onus is on you to clarify your question. Please show how a file should look from one iteration of your code, in valid JSON, and I will update my answer (ping me when you've done it).

Comment: @CDNthe2nd Note that this approach will get worse over time. You'll have a directory that just continues to grow and finding the latest file will take more time. I think you probably want to look at `sqlite3`

Comment: For some reason I cant ping - However I mean the json is not supposed to me valid - Which is not the goal for me. It could be a txt file aswell as I mentioned, I found this piece of code where I just continued since the json file looked easier (Because it automatic

Comment: opens with node++ while the textfile opens with notepad which just looks gross) - If you look my picture at the very bottom of my thread - That's how I want the code to be with your script that you have given - meaning that everytime I run the program, it creates new json file (Which your codes does) and now I just need to add the rest inside my code which is ```Saving = fname + ' ' + lname + ' - ' + email``` which will be added inside the latest json you created.

Comment: @CDNthe2nd I see it. I'm working on a big edit on the answer.

Comment: @CDNthe2nd I have edited to show a different way. What you're currently using is not sustainable as the system grows. I think sqlite3 is a better way to go; one database, all the data in once place, and easily query-able.

Comment: Oh god! This looked beautiful! I think I might start using a database for this, I will go and see how it is with sqlite3 since I dont have big knowledge of it so why not! But I did get alot of help with you so im happy!

Comment: @CDNthe2nd my code should now be fully runnable on your own system so you can see what every stage does (the first time I edited in the sqlite part it would crash for you). If you feel that this has answered your question, I would be grateful if you would accept it as answered.

Comment: @CDNthe2nd oops, the exception was not correct. Now it will run with copy/paste.

Answer (score 1):

The JSON file should contain a list of strings. You should read the current contents of the file into a variable, append to the variable, then rewrite the file.

```
with open("data.json", "r") as f:
    data = json.load(f)
data.append(firstname + ' ' + lastname+ ' - ' + email)
with open("data.json", "w") as f:
    json.dump(data, f)
```

Comment: Oh but that would just be re-written by the same data.json correct? What I wish is that its gonna create a new json file instead of running the same data.json file. So in that case it would be data2.json - data3.json and so on...

Comment: I really doubt this is what they want, though it's much closer. I think they have a lot of misconceptions here. The relies on the initial JSON having a list structure, but really they probably want a nested dictionary that they _update_ rather than dumping new data

Comment: I mean right now I do have a Json file that re-writes and it works flawless - but I wanna learn how it is if you want to create new data.json files for every run you do!

Comment: @CDNthe2nd It's not the same data, because of `data.append(...)`

Comment: @roganjosh Yes, a dictionary would be even better, but I didn't want to redesign too much.

Comment: @CDNthe2nd If you append to a JSON file the way you're doing it, it's not valid JSON any more. A JSON file can only contain one object, not multiple objects. If you want multiple items, they need to be in a container like a list.

Comment: Oh I mean.. It doesn't need to be beautiful or Json validated. I did Json because I found the code in a tutorial, It could be a txt file aswell. Just as long as it print out a Title and then the data under the titles.

Comment: If you just want to write a string, use `f.write(Saving + "\n")`

Answer (score 0):

I think what you could do is to use seek() for files and write in the related position of the json file . for example you need to update firstname , you seek for the : after firstname , and update the text there. 
There are examples here : 
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/file_seek.htm

Comment: Oh I think there might been an missunderstanding here - Basically the Infotext has First name LAst name and so on which is inside my script (Just random names basically and emails)

but what I need and wish to do is basically to create new json file where it saves all the data. So everytime I run the script, it creates new json data file with the latest data used in the script.